# how to enable detailed errors from useQuery Apollo hook - graphql

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server, grandstack

I've an Apollo fullstack application generated with GRANDstack template, and a i've added a query that is probably wrong!

I got this error: `Response not successful: Received status code 400`

So, i've tried to add `errorPolicy: 'all` to  `useQuery` hook

`useQuery(MY_QUERY,  {errorPolicy: 'all', variables: {`

but i still get a generic network error `Response not successful: Received status code 400`

what i don't know is where to act, on the apollo-server? on the apollo-client? elsewhere?  i'm using the default configuration of GRANDStack

Comment: full **network** response?

Comment: You're right! i thought the detailed errors was in the message property of the error variable (destructured from the hook) .
and in the network response there are the details of the error, without  `errorPolicy: 'all'` as well. Stupid me!